# Java H2 dynamically inserting data

Tags: java, sql, h2

Good day to you all
I am trying to import specified tables from access db to store it in a H2 embedded db to be used locally and update changes back to server (access) whenever connection is possible.
But as code below shows i am stuck at inserting dynamically data to the newly created H2 database.
I am getting this error
    org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "1" not found; SQL statement:
    INSERT INTO Users  ( `ID_USER`, `Nt_id`, `Name`, `Level`, `Psw_Admin` ) VALUES ( `1` ,`*****` ,`*******` ,`ALL` ,`*****` ) [42122-181]

As you see i have used preparedstatement, and used quotes (because the columns newly created are VARCHAR all) yet none of the above solved the issue
here is my code of inserting:

```
                while (rs.next()){

                    String object="";
                    String item="";
                    for (int i=1;i<=columncount;i++){
                        object=rs.getObject(i)+"";

                                 if (i==1){
                                    item="`"+item+object;
                                }else if (i==columncount){
                                    item=item+"` ,`"+object+"`";
                                } else{
                                    item=item+"` ,`"+object;
                                }
                                System.out.println(object);
                                }
                    PreparedStatement pst3=conn2.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Users "+" ( "+columnnamepst3+" ) VALUES ( "+item+" )");

                            pst3.executeUpdate();
                            pst3.close();
                            System.out.println("Done...next row");
                }

                rs.close();
```

rs is the result set from access db
conn2 is the connection to H2

EDIT1: corrected the code quoted
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you're not forced into to do this on your own, then you should think about using a JPA framework like Hibernate to handle all database related stuff for you. This will avoid problems like this.

Comment: @Tom If he needs to sync the changes back to the server, JPA will probably only complicate things.

Comment: You should re-read a tutorial about prepared statements, because you don't seem to understand how they work. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: @JB Nizet: i have tried using preparedstatement with "?" and .setString(1, item); it still didnt work i get the same error

Comment: I even tried this _italic_ **bold** `String sqlstm="INSERT INTO Users "+" ( "+columnnamepst3+" ) VALUES ( "+item+" )";
      Statement pst3=conn2.createStatement();
      
        pst3.executeUpdate(sqlstm);
        pst3.close();`  and still same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem seems to be the using of backticks (`) for the string values. Use apostrophes (') instead.

```
while (rs.next()) {
    String object="";
    String item="";
    for (int i=1;i<=columncount;i++) {
        object=rs.getObject(i)+"";
        if (i==1) {
            item="'"+item+object;
        } else if (i==columncount) {
            item=item+"' ,'"+object+"'";
        } else {
            item=item+"' ,'"+object;
        }
        System.out.println(object);
      }
      PreparedStatement pst3=conn2.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Users ( "+columnnamepst3+" ) VALUES ( "+item+" )");
      pst3.executeUpdate();
      pst3.close();
      System.out.println("Done...next row");
  }
  rs.close();
```

### EDIT

As your column names seem to be prepared beforehand, you could use `PrepareStatement`'s parameter passing abilities:

```
String item="";
for (int i = 1; i <= columncount; i++) {
    items += (i == 1 ? "" : ", " ) + "?";
}
PreparedStatement pst3=conn2.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Users ( "+columnnamepst3+" ) VALUES ( "+item+" )");
while (rs.next()) {
    for (int i=1;i<=columncount;i++) {
        pst3.setString(i,rs.getString(i));
    }
    pst3.executeUpdate();
    System.out.println("Done...next row");
}
pst3.close();
rs.close();
```

Should also add some error handling (`try` blocks).

Answer (score 0):

So in another forum someone proposed this solution and it worked so i am posting it maybe it'll help someone else

```
 String additif="VALUES (";
                for(int i1=1;i1<=columncount;i1++){
                    if(i1!=columncount){
                        additif=additif+"?,";
                        }else{
                            additif=additif+"?)";
                            }
                    }while (rs.next()){

                    ArrayList<String> object=new ArrayList<String>();

                    for (int i1=1;i1<=columncount;i1++){

                        object.add(""+rs.getObject(i1));

                                System.out.println(object);
                                }
                    PreparedStatement pst3=conn2.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO `"+Tabledb+"`  "+additif);
                    for(int i1=0;i1<object.size();i1++){
                    pst3.setString(i1+1, object.get(i1));}

                            pst3.executeUpdate();
                            pst3.close();
                            System.out.println("Done...next row");
                }

                rs.close();
                conn.close();
                System.out.println("Done!");
```